# End marks: are they a good idea?

Tags: typography

I'm currently writing my thesis and I have come up with old thesis that have an end mark at the last chapter.  It usually is a small centered sign.

So, my question: should I use it? is it a normal practice?  ---Please bear in mind that there is nothing about it in my school's requirements, so anything is possible.

...extra question: Do you happen to know what end marks are better for a technical document, i.e., a PhD Thesis?

**EDIT**:  Here is the last page of Lev Bishop's PhD thesis so you can see what I'm talking about.  (Full thesis here: http://www.levbishop.org/thesis/Bishop-thesis.pdf)
[image]

Comment: could you place a screenshot of the page in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sign you are talking about is [FLEURON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_%28typography%29) and [DINGBAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat).

“It can also be used to fill the whitespace that result from the indentation of the first line of a paragraph,on a line by itself to divide paragraphs in a highly stylized way, to divide lists, or for pure ornamentation”

[image]

Every education organisation has its own requirements of how the thesis should be built, thus it is better to follow the rules of your particular institution.

From my point of view you can place tiny beautiful fleurons in your work according to the general theme and topic, it adds value and the feeling of solid work. However, the end point - it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Ilan.  As I mentioned, there are no rules for the dissertation (only the cover) so pretty much everything goes.  I'm not thinking about putting these things in the indentations or between paragraphs, but rather at the very end of the last chapter to give a sensation of "that's it" (see http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/glyphs/end-marks)

Comment: @MarioS.E. end marks are a case of fleorons actually

Comment: Do you think I should use them? Are they deprecated?  Are they off the line in a dissertation?

Comment: @MarioS.E. it is up to you - to use or not. I like the idea. They are not deprecated and can add "look" value to your work if used wisely and in proportion.

Comment: Are there any rules for the use of these symbols?  Say, if I would like to use the \AE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86)  instead of a flower?

Comment: Yes, definitely. If the symbols you want to use is in the font you have by law - you are free to insert it to any work you want. If you want use some special symbols not related to font you have - you should check any particular case on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Use them if you want to. I think this is more common (but not very, any more) in non-tech academic fields.

Personally, I think it adds a little flourish and can be nice as long as you do not do it for every single page.

And of course, there are masses of other alternatives to that specific glyph. You might be surprised, your default fonts often have a few. The old-school connotations can be a nice contrast to tech content.

Answer (score 1):

While Ilan is correct that the specific glyph is a Fleuron, there are various terms for the general concept:

- [Tombstone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_%28typography%29)
- [-30-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%80%9330%E2%80%93)
- [End Sign](http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/glyphs/end-marks)

As always with type, there are no hard-and-fast rules or definitions surrounding this. It typically will come down to a style/aesthetic decision on your part.

I can't say if they are common in a thesis or not. They are very common in magazines, less common but not out of the ordinary at the end of chapters in books, and you will also seem them as a flourish on a lot of web site articles as well.